# Run Silverlight with Apache Server (Under linux)

Tags: linux, silverlight, apache

I need to deploy a Silverlight 2.0 application to an Apache Server, but it's under Linux.

Is this possible? I mean, Do I need .Net 3.5 installed in the server and a Web Site that can execute Asp.Net?

Thanks for you help...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the apache server is just serving up the silverlight application without any ASPX pages then you should be fine.  Silverlight is a client side technology so it shouldn't require .NET on the server (unless of course you are hosting the silverlight application on an ASPX page).

If you want to view the silverlight content from a client machine running linux then you will need to look into installing Moonlight as Sam pointed out.

EDIT: Tim Sneath has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2008/03/18/configuring-a-web-server-to-host-silverlight-content.aspx) that explains what needs to be configured on the web server to be able to host silverlight content.  In short you need configure the following MIME types:

> .xaml - application/xaml+xml
>
> .xap - application/x-silverlight-app

Comment: Ok, thanks. 

I still having some doubts, but I'll ask again when I need it. :)

Comment: We have a silverlight 2 app delivered by apache on a debian, it works flawlessly

Comment: Doubts? Why? It's just like serving up an image from a web server, or a Flash SWF file.

Answer (score 5):

I had to define more MIME types than KevB suggests:

```
application/manifest            .manifest
application/xaml+xml            .xaml
application/x-ms-application    .application
application/x-ms-xbap           .xbap
application/octet-stream        .deploy
application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument  .xps
```

Answer (score -2):

You should take advantage of [silverlight streaming](http://silverlight.live.com/). It is free upto 10 mins of video @ 1.4 Mbps.

Instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851621.aspx

[samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851598.aspx)

Comment: beta ended: "Content that was hosted on the beta is no longer available"