# Silverlight hosted on Linux

Tags: linux, silverlight

I am interested in Silverlight development, but due to expensive Windows Server licenses , I'm strongly considering running SL on Linux. I understand that it's a client-side technology, but I also need to be able to interact with server-side code via web services. I found out that Java (i.e. C# alike) can be used on the server side, but just wondering, would I be able to take advantage of Silverlight (development would start in Silverlight 5) in its entirety if I hosted data-driven SL content on Linux Servers? What would I lose if the back end was not ASP.NET?

Note that I just want to host content on Linux servers. The users would still need Windows or Mac to run SL.

Also I am aware of the Mono team, but as far as I know their implementation is not compatible with the latest version of SL or ASP.NET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Silverlight with Apache Server (Under linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729294/run-silverlight-with-apache-server-under-linux)

Comment: how is that a duplicate of that post?

Comment: Because it's about hosting Silverlight applications on Linux? I could be wrong and if I am there won't be any more close votes and this one will expire.

Answer (score 0):

You can host/deploy Silverlight solutions on a Linux/Apache server relatively easily.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729294/run-silverlight-with-apache-server-under-linux) for more info.

Consuming a webservice from a SL app shouldn't really matter on what language the service is written in.

Answer (score 0):

We've produced a relatively complex music synth in Silverlight which is hosted on and consumes services (Java + Scala) from a linux machine - www.knownote.net