# host silverlight application on normal apache web server?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

is it possbiel to host a silverlight application on a normal apache web server?

i mean without asp.net. (just like flash)

Comment: The question is already answered here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729294/run-silverlight-with-apache-server-under-linux

Comment: its from 2009, i hope some things have changed

Comment: Silverlight is a client-side application, unless you have ASPX content, you're fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight can be hosted from apache just fine.  The only thing you need to worry about is that you have the proper MIME types set up.  You must have at least `.xap` files set up to serve a content type of `application/x-silverlight-app`.  If your silverlight app is dynamically grabbing files from your server, you might need e.g. `.xaml` files to be served as `application/xaml+xml`.

To set MIME types with apache, you can either use the `AddType` directive in a `.htaccess` file, or edit apache's `mime.types` file directly.