# same domain, two servers...one linux, one windows

Tags: apache, iis, subdomain

I would like the great majority of my site to be on a linux server, but I would like a small section of my site to be able to host silverlight apps.

Is it possible to have two servers, one linux and the other windows under the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider hosting your Silverlight on Linux too - you can do it.

[Run Silverlight with Apache Server (Under linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729294/run-silverlight-with-apache-server-under-linux)